# How to present page with different transition (push / modal) in Flutter with Getx?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a page that can present in two ways, modally and push, based on where this page gets initiated.

I use `toNamed` to present those pages, but the problem is I can't pass `fullscreenDialog` flag at the call site. I expected something like this:

```
Get.toNamed('pageName', fullscreenDialog: false);
```

So, do I need to have two routes and two pages for this kind of job? Something like this:

```
GetPage(
  name: 'pageNameDialog',
  page: () => QuestionPage(),
  fullscreenDialog: true,
  binding: QuestionBinding(),
),

GetPage(
  name: 'pageNamePush',
  page: () => QuestionPage(),
  fullscreenDialog: false,
  binding: QuestionBinding(),
),
```

I think it should be a better way, but I'm really new to Flutter and getx and don't know what I should search for. Does anyone have a solution for this? Otherwise, I might have to double my route and page which is quite redundant.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out ? we have same issue where we want to dynamically change the transition animation between pages at run time, using GetPage routing in GetX. We should really be able to do something like Get.toNamed('page1', transition: Transition.fadeIn...) but if you DONT override the "transition" property, it defaults to the originally defined transition

Answer (score 6):

Create a class like this

```
class Go {
  /// Similar to **Navigation.push()**
  static Future<T?> to<T>(dynamic page, {dynamic arguments, Transition? transition, bool? opaque}) async {
    return await Get.to<T>(page,
        arguments: arguments,
        transition: transition ?? Transition.rightToLeft,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
        opaque: opaque);
  }

  /// Similar to **Navigation.pushReplacement**
  static Future<dynamic> off(dynamic page, {dynamic arguments, Transition? transition}) async {
    Get.off(
      page,
      arguments: arguments,
      transition: transition ?? Transition.rightToLeft,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    );
  }

  /// Similar to **Navigation.pushAndRemoveUntil()**
  static Future<dynamic> offUntil(dynamic page, {Transition? transition}) async {
    Get.offUntil(
        GetPageRoute(
          page: page,
          transition: transition ?? Transition.rightToLeft,
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
        ),
        (route) => false);
  }
}
```

then inside your view or controller

```
// BEST PRACTICE
// you can pass any object. 
var args = {'data': 'data that you want to pass'};
Go.to(() => const HomeView(), arguments: args);
```

Now to get the value that you passed in `HomeView` use the code below.

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();

    var args = Get.arguments['data'];
    
    // ... 

  }
}
```

A similar approach is applicable to others also.

Comment: work correctly thank's.

Comment: Can we add transition in Get.offNamed method? if No then How can I add transition In it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your flag as an argument, like this :

```
Get.toNamed('pageName', arguments: true);
```

And on the page where you are going you can tap into :

```
Get.arguments;
```

This will return true on pageName.

Now **arguments** parameter type is dynamic so you can pass any and also if you want multiple you can pass List or Map as well.

Hope the is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I try to change the presentation animation not passing an argument. Is there a way I can use this argument to change the animation?